# Amortized analysis (accounting/banker's method) for tree operations

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, amortized-analysis, average-case

Suppose we have a tree data structure with root $r$ with two operations:

Add($x, y$) - adds the node $y$ as a child to the node $x$

Zip($x$)- this makes the node $x$ and all of $x$'s ancenstors direct children of the root. So if we had a tree like $r \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4$ then Zip($3$) would make a new tree with root $r$ and children $1, 2, 3$ and $4$ as a child of $3$.

Say Add has cost $1$ and Zip($x$) has cost = length of path from root to $x$

We want to see that the amortized cost of a sequence of Adds and Zips is $\leq 2$ per operation. We want to use the banker's/accountant method to do this.

I'm a bit lost here and would appreciate the help.

Comment: How many Add()s does it take for a Zip() to take cost $k$?

Comment: $k-1$ many I should think.

Comment: is that incorrect? Either way I'm confused on how to apply that for the algorithm- the whole notion of credits confuses me and I would appreciate a walkthrough of sorts if you don't mind.

Comment: Looks correct, give or take up to one. Moreover, it is *so close* to an answer to your original problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow!

Comment: What do you make of en.wikipedia's [dynamic array](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis#Examples) example?

Comment: $k$ adds would then be compensated by a cost $k$ (or $k+1$?) cost zip so we get something like average cost $\frac{k + k + 1}{k + 1} < 2$? Is that the idea?

Comment: Except the problem is that we don't know how many adds precedes a zip; the operations are an arbitrary interleaving. Is this where the banker's method comes in?

Answer (score 1):

A new node $x$ can be inserted as a child of some non-root node. From how you describe it, this operation takes constant time. Now when $x$ is touched during a `zip` for the first time, you need to pay for the cost of making it a child of the root. But observe that when $x$ becomes a child of the root it will remain like that hereafter. Node $x$ can still be involved in a zip later when one if its descendant is zipped, but there is no need to transfer $x$, hence it will not incur any cost. Thus, you will only need to pay for transfering node $x$ once.

From this, hopefully you can see how much coin you will assign to `add` so you can save and have enough payment later when a newly inserted node is involved in a zip for the first time.

Comment: So... I want to say that I should add 1$ to each add that I do (to a non-root node). This way when I zip it later I should have exactly enough from each of the ancenstors of the thing being zipped. Is that right?

Comment: Yes you add an extra $1 for each add. I say extra since you would need another dollar for the cost of the add and from that you get your desired amortized cost per operation.

Comment: Just checking but the amortized cost is just the total amount deposited (cost + "extra stuff") using this method? Does this mean that the amortized cost is exactly $2$? Sorry I understand how the deposits should be made but not how the amortized cost is calculated based on this deposit

Comment: The amortized cost is the amount you allocate to the operation. So in this case you set 2 for add. So the amortized cost of add is 2. Now how much do you think you have assigned for zip?

Comment: $0$ yeah, since it's being compensated by all the add deposits?

Comment: That's right. so from that the amortized cost of each operation is at most 2

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's clear now. Appreciate it!

Comment: No worries, glad I can help